# Using an expression in a numeric form control

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access form with a textbox bound to a currency field in a table. As expected, anything other than a numerical entry generates an error. Occasionally, users need to enter several amounts and have those added together and the result entered into the currency field.

To accomplish this, I would like users to enter an equal sign followed by a valid arithmetical string which would evaluate to a number exactly as they would in an Excel cell. For example, if a user enters "=5.31+2" I want the field to evaluate to "7.31" and use that as the value passed to the table when the record is updated or saved. The current workaround is to use the Calculator application but that isn't the ideal solution.

I tried the following code and applied it to both the BeforeUpdate and OnLostFocus events of the textbox (named "tbxTotal_Paid") but neither worked. I simply got "The value you entered is not valid for this field" error.

```
Dim charCt As Integer
Dim evalStr As String

If Left(tbxTotal_Paid, 1) = "=" Then
    charCt = Len(tbxTotal_Paid)
    evalStr = Right(tbxTotal_Paid, charCt - 1)
    Me.tbxTotal_Paid = CCur(evalStr)
End If
```

Is this simply applying the code to the incorrect event or is this a coding issue? Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me your code looks fine but you might put it in the wrong place.

Like you said Acess is giving you this error because the textbox is bound to the currency-field. So it will never accept non-numerical values because the value-checking code fires even before the before_update-event.

I think the best solution would be to hide your bound text box using `Me.tbxTotal_Paid.Visible = False` and creating a surrogate textbox which is not bound. You put your code in the beforeUpdate-Event or Change-Event of your surrogate. At the end you should check your final result with `IsNumeric()`. That way your surrogate textbox writes only correct values to your bound hidden textbox and only numbers arrive at your table.

An alternative would be to change the currency column to a string-field but this would not be wise because of potential wrong data in your database.